# How to file sort in bash script

Tags: bash

i am write code for this question

Access the sum file and sort those values in ascending order and save to another
file called sum_sorted.

i wrote this code for this problem

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=$(($1+$2))
echo "Sum is : $sum" >> sum
sort sum > sumsort
```

but my output is like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSI7m.png)

sort file start with big number why is this ?

Comment: For the future, please also look at [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `-n` (numeric) switch to your sort. Right now it is sorting alphabetically: just like A < AARDVARK < B, you have 1 < 10 < 2. You have to tell `sort` to treat your numbers like numbers, not words.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
sum=$(($1+$2))
echo "Sum is : $sum" >> sum
sort -n sum > sumsort

Comment: Yeah, I didn't test on your input (_because it was in an image!_). You also need `-k4` because your number is in the fourth field.